# Isometry $\implies$ reflection or rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

> Every isometry that fixes the origin is either a rotation about the origin or a reflection in a line through the origin.

How can I prove this theorem?
Proving the converse is easy and I know how to do that.

What I know:
The rotation about the origin through an angle $\theta$ in the positive direction is described by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta &\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
and the reflection in the line through the origin that makes an angle $\theta/2$ with the $x$-axis is described by
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta &\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta &-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Do you know that the matrix of an isometry (fixing the origin) is orthogonal? Now there should be two cases depending on the determinant...

Comment: @ronno Suppose $V$ is a complex inner product space and $S\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Then I know that the following are equivalent: i) $S$ is an isometry; ii) There is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $S$ whose corresponding eigenvalues all have absolute value $1$. How do I apply this result to prove the theorem?

Comment: What is the $V$ for which you think this theorem should apply?

Comment: @ronno $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean inner product

Comment: @Nomas2 It's worth noting that the lemma you mentioned only works because $V$ is a *complex* inner product space. There is an orthonormal eigenbasis of $\mathbf{C}$ induced by a rotation, but a rotation in $\mathbf{R}$ fixes no nontrivial point, thus has no nontrivial eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product, then it must take the standard basis vector $e_1$ to a unit vector, ie of the form $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ for some $\theta$. Similarly $Ae_2 = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ for some $\phi$. Since $\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle = 0$, we must also have $\langle Ae_1, Ae_2\rangle = 0$, ie
$$0 = \cos\theta \cos \phi + \sin \theta \sin \phi = \cos(\theta - \phi).$$
So without loss of generality, $\phi = \pi/2 + \theta$ or $\phi = 3\pi/2 + \theta$. Plugging these in and writing $Ae_1$ and $Ae_2$ as the columns gives you those two matrices.